# Jest: how to count call from mock methods called via `call` or `apply`?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

How can I use mocks to count function calls made via `call` or `apply`

```
// mylib.js
module.exports = {
  requestInfo: function(model, id) {
    return `The information for ${model} with ID ${id} is foobar`;
  },
  execute: function(name) {
    return this[name] && this[name].apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
  },
};
```

```
// mylib.test.js
jest.mock('./mylib.js');

var myLib = require('./mylib.js');

test('', () => {
  myLib.execute('requestInfo', 'Ferrari', '14523');
  expect(myLib.execute.mock.calls.length).toBe(1); // Success!
  expect(myLib.requestInfo.mock.calls.length).toBe(1); // FAIL
});
```

If I explicitly call `myLib.requestInfo`, the second expectation succeeds.

Is there a way to watch module mock calls whose functions were called via `apply` or `call`?

Comment: In your example `myLib` does not have a `arrangeViewing` method. Could you please update the example , otherwise it's quite hard to get what you are trying.

Comment: Sorry, I removed the wrong methods from the example. Updated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the `jest.mock` [doc](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options):

> Mocks a module with an auto-mocked version when it is being required.

The docs could probably be improved with a better description of what "auto-mocked version" means, but what happens is that `Jest` keeps the API surface of the module the same while replacing the implementation with empty [mock functions](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api).

---

So in this case `execute` is getting called but it has been replaced by an empty mock function so `requestInfo` never gets called which causes the test to fail.

---

To keep the implementation of `execute` intact you will want to avoid auto-mocking the entire module and instead spy on the original function with something like [`jest.spyOn`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname):

```
var myLib = require('./mylib.js');

test('', () => {
  jest.spyOn(myLib, 'execute');  // spy on execute
  jest.spyOn(myLib, 'requestInfo')  // spy on requestInfo...
    .mockImplementation(() => {});  // ...and optionally replace the implementation
  myLib.execute('requestInfo', 'Ferrari', '14523');
  expect(myLib.execute.mock.calls.length).toBe(1); // SUCCESS
  expect(myLib.requestInfo.mock.calls.length).toBe(1); // SUCCESS
});
```